# Why Allah choose to create some human physically different?

Tags: islamic-philosophy, creation

I've met people who had "different physical" from me, I have a perfect hand, body, eyes, and everything that I need.

But I've found people who doesn't have hands, and feet, and other lack of physical need.

Some people got accident so they got injured, some people born in "Different physical".

If Allah is All Just, where is the justice in the case when people born in "Different Physical"? If people can choose when they will be born, I'm sure they don't want to be born like that.

Comment: Nobody will ever remember how perfect your limbs were, once you're dead. What will only matter is how perfectly you pleased/worshipped Allah with whatever form of hand/body/eye you have. Allah will try everyone according to what He gave them. This life is a test. I'm on mobile device, hence no reference s

Comment: Yes I know that this life is a test for us to go to better place, What I would like to know, is there any hikmah or a good point behind this? which make me understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another point of view. When a person is disadvantaged, it makes things more difficult for them. So when they accomplish something, it is from a lower starting point. Therefore those accomplishments are more significant. Stephen Hawking, for instance, is a world-renowned physicist and mathematician despite having very little control over his body. If I remember right, he can only move a few muscles in his face. Something you might consider is whether Allah is demonstrating the frailty of the human body and the comparative strength of the human soul. In the end, even they may well benefit by learning how they can overcome obstacles.

Comment: yes this answer make me understand. Thanks for the answer.